# Do merchant silicons have built-in TCAM?

Tags: tcam

Regarding advancements in lookup algorithms (as AlgoMatch by Arista) and maybe other new technology advancements, Is TCAM a necessary module for networking silicons?
Do merchant silicon like Broadcom chipsets have on-chip TCAM? if yes, Isn't it enough so there is no need to place external TCAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both variants, internal and external TCAM, exist. While internal is the best choice and more common for lowest cost and lowest latency, external TCAM enables a higher scalability for the required tables (routes, ACLs, QoS, etc).

For instance, Broadcom's [StrataDNX series](https://www.broadcom.com/products/ethernet-connectivity/switching/stratadnx) supports external memory while the less scalable [StrataConnect series](https://www.broadcom.com/products/ethernet-connectivity/switching/strataconnect) doesn't.

Comment: So... Anyway, a chipset needs TCAM for networking function, right?

Comment: @A.A Yes, either on-chip or external.